# MongoDB : does it need 2 mongos per shard?

Tags: mongodb

All in the title : do we need 2 mongos per shard in MongoDB ? I am not sure to understand exactly what mongos are for and if my website will communicate with them or if it is something internal to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cluster set up (with shards, not to be confused with replica set), then you have to have `mongos` instances deployed. It's a router process. It knows which data resides where. Application talks to `mongos`, it routes the request to corresponding shard. Talking to shards directly is strongly discouraged.

You must have at least one `mongos` process. You can have more, they have small resource footprint. I usually deploy one `mongos` per application server.

Comment: On a load-balanced web-server cluster, I was wondering if it's better to have one mongos per web server or have individual mongos servers where each web server can connect to in a pool.

Answer (score 1):

A mongos is basically nothing more than a router which gathers a configuration of your cluster from config servers, caches that config, and uses it to route targeted and scatter and gather operations within a cluster of shards. It can also be used for aggregation as such if aggregation queries are common in your app the mongos can take some CPU and memory, however, for the most part they have no weight and can run on the smallest server.

You do not require 2 mongos, the number depends upon the operations being sent through that router. You can in theory do with one, however, that isn't very redundant and cerates a single point of failure, 2 makes that less possible.